# Stack of polymorphed classes

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism, derived

dear C++ professionals. I got a problem. I have a program, which has 1 abstract class base_class and 2 derived classes: sippeers and dbget. It also has 2 threads. First thread gets commands from user, second thread pocesses these commands. Both derived classes represent different commands. So, I have to create some kind of stack, where I should put user commands from first thread and get them in second thread to process. To make one stack for all commands, I got to use polymorphism. First, I tried to use std::list. But there was first problem: I can't make a list of abstract classes. Then I tried to use boost::ptr_list, but there was the second problem: classes, created in the first thread, dissappear with end of procedure, that created them. So pointers become illegal. The question: what kind of realization should I use? It looks like I must store every copy of derived class. But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An std::queue of `shared_ptr<base_class>` is the most straightforward solution to pass classes from 1 thread to another without worring about memory management.  Combined with a conditional variable to signal that the queue is not empty, so the consumer-thread can wait.

For the polymorphism part, have an extra virtual function (execute()?), so the consumer thread  shouldn't be aware what class it actually receives.

Comment: Will it be the solution? I could use
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<base_class>> commands
First thread could put pointers into this list, second thread could do something like:
while (!commands.empty())
    {
    base_command c = commands.front();
    commands.pop_front();
    }

Comment: Except for the shared_ptrs (which we didn't know of at the time), this is the (simplified) solution that we use.  We use std::queue because that is all that is needed.  You could use std::list if you want to remove/replace some command-instances.  Don't forget a 'condition variable'/monitor/semaphore if you want to block on an empty/full queue.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I tried to use std::list. But there was first problem: I can't make a list of abstract classes.

You can, however, create an `std::list` containing *pointers* to the abstract base class, e.g.

```
std::list<base_class *> commands;
```

> Then I tried to use boost::ptr_list, but there was the second problem: classes, created in the first thread, dissappear with end of procedure, that created them. So pointers become illegal.

Do you mean the new commands are created on the stack of the first thread? Don't do that - the first thread doesn't know when the second thread finished handling the commands, so the first thread shouldn't define when they end. Just let the first thread allocate objects using `new`.

That being said, your use case sounds like a classical example of the producer-consumer problem. Consider having a look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) on this for some inspiration on how to implement such a system properly (it's not too hard to get it wrong).